# Model invalid when adding in Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Page which submits most of the required fields for `MyUser`, however, some I want created manually before adding to the database.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    //Other MyUser attributes set using form
    MyUser.Date = DateTime.Now;
    MyUser.Name = User.Identity.Name;
    MyUser.Details = "Sort This";

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page(); //Claims MyUser.Details is null
    }

    _context.User.Add(MyUser);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

My issue is that when `!ModelState.IsValid` is called, it says that `MyUser.Details` is null and fails. As you can see, `MyUser.Details` was set above (it should be string). I have no issues setting `Date` or `Name` this way.

Comment: `ModelState` is determined on the values that came from the request, it doesn't matter that you modify them afterwards. The problem is that you are asking for values that the client doesn't set, so you need to use an appropriate ViewModel

Comment: How do I do that in a razor page? I thought it replaced ViewModels?

Comment: Instead of having `MyUser` as the bound property, bind a ViewModel (which really just means a *different* type with only the fields provided by the form) and then map from that to whatever `MyUser` is. You can check `ModelState` for the user input to ensure it's valid.

Comment: " I thought it replaced ViewModels?" A viewmodel is just a fancy name for a simple class whos properties will match the submitted data. Nothing clever. Razor pages has not replaced them in any way, to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by comment:

Instead of having MyUser as the bound property, bind a ViewModel (which really just means a different type with only the fields provided by the form) and then map from that to whatever MyUser is. You can check ModelState for the user input to ensure it's valid.